# how to indicate when Column property "width" is changed on WPF DevExpress grid

Tags: wpf, grid, devexpress

does anyone knows how to indicate when Column property "width" is changed on this grid? It is no such event like ColumnWidthChanged in this grid...
I want to save my widths of columns to database later, when tthis event is occoured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not such oportunity to notify that. The only way - to implement such event for yuorself.

Comment: You don't describe how to implement such an event. Any chance you can post the implementation details for others to re-use?